# How to open a folder in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access-2010

I need to open some folder with it's links in MS-Access. My code is below but it doesn't work:

```
        DataSet DSOne = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            adp.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            adp.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;
            adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = " select Folder from Sheet where ID  like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or OfficialDossier like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or Family like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or FirstName like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or approve like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or City like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or Department like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' or Organization like '%" + textBox9.Text + "%' ";
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox9.Text);
            adp.Fill(DSOne, "Folder");
            string p = "Folder";
            string args = string.Format("/e, /select, \"{0}\"", p);
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = "explorer";
            info.Arguments = args;
            Process.Start(info);     
        }
```

This code is two part: One part is until to `adp.Fill(SDOne, "Folder");` and it work properly! I get the result with a `DataGridView` as `datasource` and `datamember`.
Second part from `string p = "Folder";` work too! When I Get an address to string, this code open it.
I think the problem is transferring between `adp.Fill (DSOne, "Folder");` and String and I don't know how I must put `datamember` to string.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: As usual, saying that your code doesn't work is not very helpful. Please explain what doesn't work, what error messages you get and all the info you suppose are relevant to your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your execute the command to retrieve the folder from your database (more on this later) but you forget to read that value and use it to open your filesystem folder

```
adp.Fill(DSOne, "Folder");
if(DSOne.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // Here you are sure that the first table of the dataset contains at least one record.
    // So you could retrieve it (Rows[0]) and then access the first column 
    // of that row (Rows[0]["Folder"])
    string p = DSOne.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Folder"].ToString();
    string args = string.Format("/e, /select, \"{0}\"", p);
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "explorer";
    info.Arguments = args;
    Process.Start(info);     
}
```

Any kind of string concatenation to build sql command is doomed to failure. You shouldn't use that approach but always a parameterized query. In your code above it seems that you add a parameter and this parameter is never used. I suggest to change that part of the code to

```
adp.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
adp.SelectCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection1;
adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT Folder FROM Sheet 
                    WHERE ID LIKE ? or OfficialDossier LIKE ? or Family LIKE ? or 
                    FirstName LIKE ? or approve LIKE ? or City LIKE ? or 
                    Department LIKE ? or Organization LIKE ?";
string parameterValue = "%" + textBox9.Text + "%";
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", parameterValue);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", parameterValue);
```

OleDb requires the exact number of parameters added to the command collection as many placeholders are present in your query and in the same order. In your case you use always the same value extracted by a textbox and concatenated with the sql wild cards. So it seems correct to add 8 parameters all with the same value.

Comment: Thank You! Still don't work! Folder isn't first column. Is this Important in this code?

Comment: No its not important because I use directly the column name. however your query retrieve just the folder column from the Sheet table. What is the value of p after the assignement from the table? Use the debugger and set a breakpoint after that line

Comment: Return twice of Address in p !

Comment: "F:\\Database#F:\\Database#"

Comment: Well, of course that's not a valid path to pass as argument. Now the question is why you have this data? It is stored twice or there is something in your code that doubles the content of the field?

Comment: I can't understand. this is a simple Access Database with 6th column as Folder that is a Hyperlink sort. I add the links by Edit-Hyperlink to it. that is a true link to F:\\ folder. My code is a simple page with two text Box and a button. can be cause of use ProssesStartInfo?